# How can I track memory usage for an R function that uses Rcpp?

Tags: r, profiling, rcpp

So I have a program that imports a function from C++ using Rcpp, and I want to measure its memory usage, specifically its peak memory usage. I tried Rprof but it seems I'm not getting good enough resolution, e.g. a lot of my outputs show 0 as mem.total in the output produced by summaryRprof(). I've also tried lineprof by Hadley Wickham and its results seem contradictory to what I'm getting from Rprof.

Code with rprof:

```
Rprof(NULL)
Rprof(tf <- "rprof.log", memory.profiling=TRUE, interval = .0000025)
xz <- my.function(arg1, arg2)
Rprof(NULL)
out <- summaryRprof(tf, memory = c("both"))
```

Output from Rprof:

```
$by.self
[1] self.time  self.pct   total.time total.pct  mem.total 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$by.total
             total.time total.pct mem.total self.time self.pct
".Call"               0       100         0         0      100
"C++ function"        0       100         0         0        0
"R function"          0       100         0         0        0

$sample.interval
[1] 2e-06

$sampling.time
[1] 0.000332
```

At larger intervals, the out$by.self comes back, but still shows zero for mem.total.

Code with lineprof:

```
source("my_function.r")
prof <- lineprof(my.function(arg1, arg2))
shine(prof)
```

Not sure how/if I can upload images to stackoverflow, but basically I get the shiny app interface but with just a single line ".Call".

Sorry if this is confusing, please ask if you need me to clarify anything, and thanks!

Comment: Need to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Please read _Writing R Extensions_ and particularly the sections about _memory profiling_.  As I recall you may need to have an R binary instrumented for it.  This keeps track of _all_ memory use _by R_ and as Rcpp uses R's memory allocator for its types (so that they can be returned to R) it covers then too.  Conversely, if you were to use STL types (with their own allocator) they would _not_ be covered.